# GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM macro in C#

Tags: c#, c++, macros, mouseevent, mousewheel

How would I go about using the [GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro in C#?

Comment: A sanity check is required here.  You cannot use C# to write code that's called by a global hook.  That requires an injectable DLL.

Comment: It seems to kind of work for me from C# with dllimport but sometimes hogs windows 'n stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High-order word, signed:

```
 ((short)(wParam>>16))
```

Comment: My method: public static short GetWheelDeltaWParam(int wparam) { return (short)(wparam >> 16); }, but it always return  zero. I call it like this: GetWheelDeltaWParam((int)wParam);

Comment: If that doesn't work, try GetWDWP(unsigned int wparam) { return (short)((unsigned short)(wparam>>16)); }

Comment: unfortunately nope.. the first one should work, but it doesn't

Comment: Are you sure your wparam is correct? The problem may not be in this function. I don't see why it should be zero otherwise.

Comment: that may be the case, but I don't understand how I can move the mouse wheel and generate this event so that WHEEL_DELTA would be 0

Comment: I guess you need to post more of your code. Perhaps in a new question since this one is strictly about the macro.

Answer (score 9):

For maximum clarity, I would define a set of functions like this:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    internal static ushort HIWORD(IntPtr dwValue)
    {
        return (ushort)((((long)dwValue) >> 0x10) & 0xffff);
    }

    internal static ushort HIWORD(uint dwValue)
    {
        return (ushort)(dwValue >> 0x10);
    }

    internal static int GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(IntPtr wParam)
    {
        return (short)HIWORD(wParam);
    }

    internal static int GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(uint wParam)
    {
        return (short)HIWORD(wParam);
    }
}
```

And then use the function like so, where `wParam` is the `WPARAM` parameter you get from handling the Win32 `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` or `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` messages:

```
int zDelta = NativeMethods.GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam);
```

You might need to suppress overflow-checking in order for this to work properly. To do so, either change your project settings, or wrap the relevant conversion functions in an [`unchecked` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's the [MouseWheelEventArgs.Delta Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousewheeleventargs.delta.aspx):

> Gets a value that indicates the amount that the mouse wheel has changed.

```
private void MouseWheelHandler(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        // Do one thing
    }
    else if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        // Do the other thing
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I forgot to mention I am using global hooks from user32.dll with dllimport so I don't have access to such fancy objects..